# Runtime Exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Optional.toJavaUtil()L with Spark-BigQuery connector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-bigquery, sbt-assembly

Currently I'm trying to connect to BigQuery from Spark. I'm have built fat jar file using `sbt assembly` plugin and trying to launch the job in local mode using `spark-submit`. I'm observing `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Optional.toJavaUtil()Ljava/util/Optional;` exception as soon as Spark job is launched.

Below is the Exception Trace,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Optional.toJavaUtil()Ljava/util/Optional;
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.SparkBigQueryConfig.getOption(SparkBigQueryConfig.java:265)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.SparkBigQueryConfig.getOption(SparkBigQueryConfig.java:256)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.SparkBigQueryConfig.lambda$getOptionFromMultipleParams$7(SparkBigQueryConfig.java:273)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:1812)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.SparkBigQueryConfig.getOptionFromMultipleParams(SparkBigQueryConfig.java:275)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.SparkBigQueryConfig.from(SparkBigQueryConfig.java:119)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider.createSparkBigQueryConfig(BigQueryRelationProvider.scala:133)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider.createRelationInternal(BigQueryRelationProvider.scala:71)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider.createRelation(BigQueryRelationProvider.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:174)
    at com.bigquery.OwnDataSetReader$.delayedEndpoint$com$$bigquery$OwnDataSetReader$1(OwnDataSetReader.scala:18)
    at com.bigquery.OwnDataSetReader$delayedInit$body.apply(OwnDataSetReader.scala:6)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at com..bigquery.OwnDataSetReader$.main(OwnDataSetReader.scala:6)
    at com..bigquery.OwnDataSetReader.main(OwnDataSetReader.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:894)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

After doing some research on the exception, I found that this exception can happen due to multiple version of `guava` library. I made sure that there are no such conflicts in the final build jar, I also verified it by decompiling my jar file. No conflicts were observed, but issue still persists :(. Below is the `build.sbt` snippet,

```
name := "bigquer-connector"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
test in assembly := {}

assemblyJarName in assembly := "BigQueryConnector.jar"

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case x if x.startsWith("META-INF") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    oldStrategy(x)

}

libraryDependencies += ("com.google.cloud.spark" %% "spark-bigquery" % "0.18.0")
  .exclude("com.google.guava", "guava")
  .exclude("org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged", "jersey-guava")

libraryDependencies += "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "30.0-jre"

libraryDependencies += ("org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.3.1")
  .exclude("com.google.guava", "guava")
  .exclude("org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged", "jersey-guava")


libraryDependencies += ("org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.3.1")
  .exclude("com.google.guava", "guava")
  .exclude("org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged", "jersey-guava")
```

Below is the Main class,

```
object OwnDataSetReader extends App {

  val session = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("big-query-connector")
    .config(getConf)
    .getOrCreate()

  session.read
    .format("com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery")
    .option("viewsEnabled", true)
    .option("parentProject", "my_gcp_project")
    .option("credentialsFile", "<path to private json file>")
    .load("my_gcp_data_set.my_gcp_view")
    .show(2)

  private def getConf : SparkConf = {
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf
    sparkConf.setAppName("biq-query-connector")
    sparkConf.setMaster("local[*]")

    sparkConf
  }
}
```

Command used for launching the Spark in my local terminal : `spark-submit --deploy-mode client --class com.bigquery.OwnDataSetReader BigQueryConnector.jar`. I'm using spark version `2.3.x` on my local machine

Comment: What is line 18 in `OwnDataSetReader`?

Comment: Why do you compile the connector yourself? There are built jars both in maven central and in gs://spark-lib/bigquery/

Comment: @DavidRabinowitz , we are building fat jar which we launch on our Spark cluster. Anyways, I was able fix the issue. The issue was with `build.sbt` file where we were discarding`META-INF` folder. The config files inside `META-INF` folder of `spark-bigquery` connector are used during library bootstrap

Comment: Great! please post this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue. It was with merge strategy in my `build.sbt` file.

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case x if x.startsWith("META-INF") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x =>
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    oldStrategy(x)

}
```

I was discarding the files in `META-INF` folder. The config files inside `META-INF` folder of `spark-bigquery` connector are used during library bootstrap. So, instead of discarding, changing the strategy like below worked for me.

```
case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) =>
    (xs map {_.toLowerCase}) match {
      case ("manifest.mf" :: Nil) | ("index.list" :: Nil) | ("dependencies" :: Nil) | ("license" :: Nil) | ("licence.txt" :: Nil) | ("notice.txt" :: Nil) | ("notice" :: Nil)=>
        MergeStrategy.discard
      case ps @ (x :: xs) if ps.last.endsWith(".sf") || ps.last.endsWith(".dsa") || ps.contains("license") || ps.contains("notice") =>
        MergeStrategy.discard
      case "plexus" :: xs =>
        MergeStrategy.discard
      case "services" :: xs =>
        MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
      case _ => MergeStrategy.last
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is because of version mismatch among dependent libraries of com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery_2.11:0.18.1. It was resolved for me using com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.11:0.18.1 which brings in all the dependent libs.